# Indentation of nested method calls in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods, indentation

This is how Visual Studio 2010 is formatting a three-deep nested method call:

```
Math.Cos(
    Math.Cos(
    Math.Cos(0)));
```

Notice that it's not intending the last call. I'd expect it to indent like so:

```
Math.Cos(
    Math.Cos(
        Math.Cos(0)));
```

Any way to get VS to format like the latter?

Comment: I don't get this issue, but I've got ReSharper installed. Perhaps that might solve your problem, and I'd certainly recommend it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Edit + Advanced + Format Document command doesn't touch that code.  This is what you get when you press the Enter key.  Simply type Tab on the 3rd line.

Comment: Ah OK. I was worried that VS would undo the manual indentation when it auto formats. Thanks!